# How can I press the Enter key on Selenium using Python without finding an element?

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to enable the EasyPrivacy list on the AdBlockPlus plugin automatically using Selenium on Python. 
On the website:

https://adblockplus.org/en/features#tracking

upon clicking on the `open this dialog' link, a window/popup/alert opens up, and all I want to do is press enter. However, I have not been able to find a way to send the Enter key without finding an element on the page. Since the window/popup/alert is not html, I cannot send the Enter key.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? Emulating the keyboard with selenium is limited to the page, but there are alternatives to deal with a popup depending on the context.

Answer (score -1):

Hi after upon clicking on the `open this dialog' link, a window/popup/alert opens up do not try to hit ENTER button instead try to send TAB command via selenium and when tab control is at right place then use ENTER with selenium

hope this helps

Comment: just one thing : hacks are not good for long term maintenance

Comment: this is not hack this is one of the way to do this ,also it checks the functionality of TAB is working properly or not

Comment: what would you do in case the number of TAB press required to reach ENTER button changes because of few UI changes after some time?

Comment: @ null pointer please pay attention this is the case where you have to deal with pop up which has only to possible options (generally)accept and cancel so in future it is rare that it will change ,if it was a web page and we were dealing with tab then in that case your concern was genuine,also please let OP decide what he says